# Error side-loading Microsoft Teams add-in

Tags: office-js, microsoft-teams

When loading manifest I receive the error message "something went wrong". The manifest is included below:

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/sdk/v1.0/manifest/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json", 
  "manifestVersion": "1.0",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "id": "c946e298-5e6a-4e12-8e33-66dfd07a27c3", 
  "packageName": "com.parrot365.com",
  "developer": {
    "name": "Acrowit Inc, DBA WittyParrot Inc",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.parrot365.com/",
    "privacyUrl": "https://www.parrot365.com/privacy.html",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.parrot365.com/term.html"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "Parrot365",
    "full": "Parrot365 Teams Assistant"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "Parrot365 Teams Assistant",
    "full": "Key value proposition for users include (1) Productivity increase by up to 2.5 times (2) Consistent message deliver across your entire team (3) Personalization of message on the fly at the point of use using placeholders (4) Mass emailing with email tracking and drip campaigns using your email server which guarantees email delivery into recipients inbox"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "https://o365widget.wittyparrot.com/assets/images/widget_logo.png", 
    "color": "https://o365widget.wittyparrot.com/assets/images/wp_logo_80px.png" 
  },
  "accentColor": "#ffffff",
  "configurableTabs": [
    {
      "configurationUrl": "https://widget.parrot365.com",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
      "scopes": [ "team" ]
    }
  ],
  "staticTabs": [
    {
      "entityId": "idForPage",
      "name": "Parrot365",
      "contentUrl": "https://widget.parrot365.com",
      "websiteUrl": "http://widget.parrot365.com",
      "scopes": [ "personal" ]
    }
  ],
  
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
     "*.parrot365.com",
     "*.wittyparrot.com"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am surprised the error message is not specific, but it is what it is. I used [online validator](https://jsonschemalint.com/#/version/draft-04/markup/json) to validate your JSON against of schema. The following is the error:

```
.staticTabs[0].websiteUrl   should match pattern "^[Hh][Tt][Tt][Pp][Ss]://" "http://widget.parrot365.com"
```

Basically you cannot use non-SSL URL. by changing "**http**" to "**https**" JSON will be valid.

Comment: This is correct. You can find a full reference for the manifest schema at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/schema

Comment: One other note:  you should include your icons inside the package, not through URL:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/createpackage#icons

Comment: i have changed  http to https in static tab and changed the icon url to absolute path.But then also addin is not loading.error: something went wrong

Comment: @Leo Would you mind to update your question with current manifest? Also is there anything useful in the logs. [Logs location](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uclobby/2016/11/08/microsoft-teams-desktop-and-web-client-log-location/)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with the Full description length.  Although the schema definition allows very long entries, we were able to get your sample to load only when we reduced that long description length.  We'll log this as a bug.  Apologies for the inconvenience!

FYI if you are considering Office Store submission in the future, when the in-product app discovery is fully enabled, end users will see the entry from the metadata entered in the Seller Dashboard instead of this manifest field.